# How to extract digit(s) from the end of string

Tags: c++, c, stl

Given strings like the following:

```
   sdfsd34 
    sdfdsf1
```

I would like to extract: *34, 1*  using c++ (STL but no boost), c.

thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You’re searching for the function [`string.find_last_not_of`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/find_last_not_of):

```
string str = "sdfsd34";
size_t last_index = str.find_last_not_of("0123456789");
string result = str.substr(last_index + 1);
```

Comment: `str.substr(str.find_first_of("0123456789"))`  is OK too.

Comment: @Jeelee that depends on what OP meant. If he meant "extract everything after the first number", yours is right; if he meant "extract trailing numbers" (ie. `2` in `1337hunter2`), only Konrad is right. Visitors from the future of course can use whatever they want to do.

Answer (score 4):

A lot here depends on whether you're more comfortable with string manipulation, or with STL-style iterators and such. As @Konrad already pointed out, `std::string` has `find_last_not_of` built in, for anybody who likes string-style manipulation.

If you prefer, you can work with a string a bit more like a container, and find the first non-digit starting from the end:

```
std::string::iterator pos = std::find_if(
    mystring.rbegin(), 
    mystring.rend(), 
    std::not1(std::isdigit)).base();
```

In this case, the conversion from `reverse_iterator` to `iterator` happens to work out very nicely. The `reverse_iterator` returned by `find_if` will refer to the last element *before* a contiguous set of digits at the end of the string. The `base` of that, however, will refer to the first of the digits (or `mystring.end()` if there are no digits at the end or (unfortunately) if the whole string consists of digits).

Answer (score 3):

Initial version, using `<algorithm>`:

```
string input("aasdf43");
string matches("01234567890");

string::iterator iter = find_first_of(input.begin(), input.end(), 
        matches.begin(), matches.end());

string next(iter, input.end());

stringstream intStream(next);
int intValue;
intStream >> intValue;
```

EDIT: Better to use member function:

```
string input("aasdf43");
string matches("0123456789");
size_t offset = input.find_first_of(matches);
string next(input.substr(offset));

stringstream intStream(next);
int intValue;
intStream >> intValue;
```

Just for good measure - an `<algorithm>` version not requiring check versus all digits.

```
string::reverse_iterator iter = find_if_not(input.rbegin(), input.rend(), 
    ([&](char c) { return c >= '0' && c <= '9';}));
reverse(input.rbegin(), iter);
string reversed(input.rbegin(), iter);

stringstream intStream(reversed);
int intValue;
intStream >> intValue;
```

Comment: Good alternative. Note, however, that this will fail for strings such as `"ab12cd34"` (i.e. any string that has numbers *followed* by letters).

Comment: @Konrad - yes, this is for problem as stated and  yours is more robust.  Mine is better with member function not `<algorithm>` version.

Comment: 1) I liked the algorithms version because it was a nice alternative. It also used iterators which I prefer over indexes any time. 2) Hm. I forgot about that. But yes, it will work since `string::npos == -1` as per the standard (§21.3.6).

Comment: The version from Konrad also works for entirely numeric input, because `string::find_last_not_of` returns `string::npos` (== `(string::size_type)-1`) for not found. When adding 1, you conveniently end up with 0.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a C solution. You've to include stdio.h and ctype.h to get this to work.

```
char* str = "djafldjsalj124"; 
long n; 

char *s = str; 
while (*s && !isdigit(*s)) s++; 
if (*s)
{
 sscanf(s, "%d", &n);  
 printf("%d\n", n); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If they're always at the end, then just start at the end of the string and look for a digit, when you get to the first non digit number, then you have it.  Look at reverse_find, or find_reverse, or something like that.  It's been a long time since I've done any string manipulation in STL.  Being the old-timey c programmer that I am, I'd probably end up converting it to a char array (if it's not a super long string), and doing stupid pointer tricks, but thats just me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming str is the string in question, and i will contain a pointer to the character where the number starts...

```
char* i;
for(i = str + strlen(str) - 1; i >= str && *i >= '0' && *i <= '9'; i--);
i++;
```

Answer (score 0):

The C++ solutions already posted are pretty reasonable. In C, you can use strpbrk.  This gives the first occurance of any of a set of characters, so if it not guaranteed that the digits appear at the end of the string, you will need to call strpbrk until it returns null, saving the result of the previous call before the next call.  There is no reverse strpbrk as there is for strchr, at least that I know of.